# Red herrings in detective puzzles

Tags: puzzle-creation, mystery

OK, so I've written [several](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4075/the-serial-killer-part-1) [detective](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4263/the-serial-killer-part-2) [puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4449/the-serial-killer-part-3).

Part 1 turned out to be what I'd consider balanced for difficulty: it had a clearly-correct answer, and took about half a day to be solved.

Part 2 was an unmitigated disaster: it took 20 minutes to solve, and someone else guessed the end-game I had planned.

Part 3 was in between the two - it took about 4 hours to solve.

---

It's obviously very easy to just carpet-bomb the puzzle with red herrings all over the place, littering it with irrelevant clues. I feel that's a bit blunt though.

The converse is just as bad: if the puzzle **only** contains relevant information then someone can start anywhere and pretty quickly figure out the answer.

What I'm wondering is **given an only-relevant-information detective puzzle, how much distraction should I add**? As a supplementary question, how can I judge it to try to strike a balance between the solution and the red herrings?

Comment: In my humble opinion, a great puzzle is difficult to guess not because of red herrings but because it is illusive, and yet once you know the answer, you immediately know it is correct.

Comment: I have the exact same problem with steganographic puzzles.

Comment: In my humble opinion, red herrings are the best part of a puzzle, and you should put as many of them as you like, and cackle maniacally when someone barks up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 6):

I believe **detective puzzles** are a bit special, as in that it is in their very nature that there are only tiny amounts of *relevant* information in what is otherwise a haystack of information. It is all about *searching* and *finding*.

However, I think a good detective puzzle differentiates false information in

- just not relevant
- real red herrings. (apparently relevant but misleading)

For the second category, I think a *fair* detective puzzle should allow the red-herrings to be disregarded by logic. i.e. there should be something in the available information which with some thinking allows a clear conclusion: "*This can not be it*".   Note the difference between the conclusion "*No, it can not be because...*" and *No this is not sufficient proof for..."*  I think it should be possible, to really rule any red-herring *out* completely.

---

As for the question of *"how much..."*  , I don't think there is clear answer to that. I think it's experience and feedback from puzzle-solvers which can (iteratively) help you there to find the right balance.

My [own attempt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5674/the-untimely-death-of-dr-wenzel) was far too easy...

Comment: The point about making it logically feasible to discount a line of thinking is interesting. Do you mean that it should be possible to **know for sure** that a line of reasoning can be ignored, or would something else just clueing that and hinting that it's a distraction be acceptable, in your opinion?

Comment: @Joe: Yes, that's what I meant. A line of reasoning which is a red herring should have a *logical* reason to be known as *false for sure*. (In a fair and fun puzzle.)